# Changing a perl while loop to shell

Tags: bash, perl, shell

I'm not very familiar with shell and have the following perl script inside a bash file to run to get a file from my webserver:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { while (<>) { last if $_ eq "\r\n"; } }'
```

Is there a way to change this over to shell so that I may become independent of having perl?

Here is the full script example:

```
echo -ne "GET /file HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\n\r\n" | nc www.example.com 80 | perl -pe 'BEGIN { while (<>) { last if $_ eq "\r\n"; } }' > file
```

Thanks for any help you have to offer.

Comment: bash's [read](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html) built-in may help.

Comment: @Gowtham Thanks, I'm not very familiar with bash as well, I mostly based my code from some examples I have read about. I'm not really sure how I would go about implementing read

Comment: `wget -O file http://www.example.com/file`?

Comment: If you want to get rid of `nc`, take a look at: [how to download a file using just bash and nothing else (no curl, wget, perl, etc.)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83927/74329)

Comment: @Cyrus thanks, anyway that could be one line?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: Or you could do it all in `perl` which is ubiquitous. (And this is probably doable entirely with `curl` or `wget`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What does this do?

> ```
> perl -pe 'BEGIN { while (<>) { last if $_ eq "\r\n"; } }'
> ```

It removes everything at the beginning until a line that contains only `\r\n`. This Sed will do the same:

```
sed -e '1,/^'$'\r''$/d'
```

What this does, it deletes the range from the first line until the line that contains a `\r` (the `\n` is not part of the line in Sed).

If the input had UNIX style line endings it could be a lot simpler:

```
sed -e '1,/^$/d'
```

#### Changing a perl while loop to shell

If you mean changing that Perl to pure Bash,
without even Sed or Awk, here's one way to do it:

```
strip_until_first_blank() {
    seen_blank=
    while read line; do
        if [ "$seen_blank" ]; then
            echo $line
        elif ! [ "$line" ]; then
            seen_blank=1
        fi
    done
}
```

You can replace the Perl command in the pipeline with `strip_until_first_blank`.

You *could* also write that on a single line, but it will be hard to read:

```
{ seen_blank=; while read line; do if [ "$seen_blank" ]; then echo $line; elif ! [ "$line" ]; then seen_blank=1; fi; done; }
```

#### ... or use `curl` or `wget` ...

As [@Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus) pointed out in a comment,
you can actually replace the entire pipeline with `curl` or `wget`:

```
wget -O file http://www.example.com/file
curl -o file http://www.example.com/file
```

Comment: If I wanted to edit this command down even further to be just using shell/bash would there be anything I could use to replace nc as not all systems may have it installed? Thank you for you comment btw, this answers my question I am just asking for a bit more information.

Comment: Erm... Yes... On closer look, as @Cyrus pointed out, looks like you can simply replace all that with a simple `curl` or `wget`... See my update at the end

Comment: the point of this is to not use packages that might not be included in some systems like wget or curl. @janos

Comment: `curl` and `wget` will also handle chunked responses, which aren't uncommon. (They'll also handle compressed responses, but you're unlikely to encounter one of those without requesting it.)